# how to check all items in a list/matrix are different in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, unique, element

given an NxN matrix of lists how can i determine that all the elements in the list are unique
example inputs:

```
(check_unique_elem([[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]))
example output:
 True
(check_unique_elem([[1]]))
True
(check_unique_elem([[2,3],[6,5],[6,7]]))
False
```

Comment: What about the expected outputs?

Comment: Are the lists always nested 2 deep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements are all hashable (the ints in your example are), you can add them to a set checking for duplicates.

```
def check_unique_elem(L):
    seen = set()
    for row in L:
        for i in row:
            if i in seen:
                return False
            seen.add(i)
    return True
```

This has the advantage of exiting as soon as the first duplicate is found (shortcircuiting)

Comment: ok i appended them all to a 1 list but how do i check each item in the list if it is unique

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain

print(len(set(chain(*l))) == sum(len(s) for s in l))
```

If your lists were very big, there are more efficient ways, if not then this is a concise way to do what you want.

A bit like code golf but we could short circuit on a sublist basis:

```
l = [[8, 3, 4], [7, 5, 9], [33, 12, 22]]

st = set()
print(not any(b == -1 for b in (st.update(s) if st.isdisjoint(s)  else -1
                            for s in map(set, l))))
```

Comment: Why import `Counter`?

Comment: @Eric, it was close to `from itertools import chain` when I copied  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal, but concise:

```
def check_unique_elem(mat):
    flat = [c for row in mat for c in row]
    return len(flat) == len(set(flat))
```

Also less prone to timing attacks, in the very unlikely case that's an issue

---

Or if you want a one-liner:

```
import collections

has_duplicate = collections.Counter(c for row in mat for c in row).most_common(1)[0][1] > 1
```

Comment: I just think 20 seconds faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
def check_unique_elem(mylist):
    flattened_list = [i for sublist in mylist for i in sublist]
    return len(set(flattened_list)) == len(flattened_list)

print(check_unique_elem([[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]))
print(check_unique_elem([[1]]))
print(check_unique_elem([[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

store everything in one list then check the occurrence of each element using **count**:

```
def elements_are_unique(new_list):
    for element in new_list:
        icount = new_list.count(element)
        if icount > 1:
            return False
    return True
```